# GetValue of property in Android

Tags: java, android

I am looking for a solution to get a `Value` from a `Property` in Android.

I have an ArrayList of Person and I want to get only the property "name" and add it to an ArrayList of Strings.

The code below is in Xamarin and I am looking for the same thing in android studio. Thanks!

```
  foreach (var s in filter.Nodes)
            {
                nodeName = s.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(s).ToString();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();

for(Person data: filterList){
List.add(data.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> names = people.stream()
  .map(x -> x.name)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also I'm unsure why you're still using Java when Kotlin exists...

```
val names = people.map { it.name }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Model class which will contain properties name like "public String Name". You can use forEach loop to iterate for that Model class and access the property.

```
public class User{
    @SerializedName("Name")
    public String name;
}
```

MainActivity code will be like

```
for(User user: "your_response"){
  list.add(user.name);
}
```